# jQuery AJAX contact form in popup box

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm building a contact form that appears in a jQuery popup box.  When you click submit, it uses AJAX and a PHP script to send the email.  My problem is that, well, it doesn't work.  It goes ahead and submits the form as regular and the email is never sent.  In the .ajax function, neither the success nor error function is called.  Here is my code:

The popup opens when you click on this: (This part works)

```
<a href="mailto:info@visionprintmedia.com" class="email">info@visionprintmedia.com</a>
```

The jQuery script:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.email').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('body').append('<div id="popupshadow"></div><div id="popup"></div>');
        $('#popupshadow').css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:0.7},1000);
        $('#popup').css({opacity:0}).delay(1200).animate({opacity:1},800);
        $('#popup').html('<form class="contact" action="#" method="none"><table class="contact"><tr><td class="input-name">Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" size="25" /></td></tr><tr><td class="input-email">Email:</td><td><input type="email" name="email" size="25" /></td></tr><tr><td class="input-phone">Phone:</td><td><input type="phone" name="phone" size="25" /></td></tr><tr><td class="input-message">Message:</td><td><textarea name="message" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea></td></tr><tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Send" /></td></tr></table><input type="hidden" name="to" value="' + $(this).attr('href').slice(7) + '"/></form><a href="mailto:' + $(this).attr('href').slice(7) + '" class="cancel">Send using your own mail program.</a>');
        $('form.contact').submit(function(event) {
            $('form.contact td').css('color','#000000');

            var name = $('form.contact input[name="name"]').val();
            var email = $('form.contact input[name="email"]').val();
            var phone = $('form.contact input[name="phone"]').val();
            var message = $('form.contact textarea[name="message"]').val();

            var valid = true;
            if(name == "") {
                valid = false;
                $('td.input-name').css('color','#FF0000');
            }
            if(email == "" && phone == "")
                valid = false;
            if(email == "")
                $('td.input-email').css('color','#FF0000');
            if(phone == "")
                $('td.input-phone').css('color','#FF0000');
            if(message == "") {
                valid = false;
                $('td.input-message').css('color','#FF0000');
            }

            if(valid) {
                $.ajax({url : 'http://nickentin.com/design/projects/visionprintmedia/js/contact.php',
                        data : {name : name,
                                email : email,
                                phone : phone,
                                message : message,
                                to : to},
                        type : 'post',
                        success : function(data) {
                            alert("SUCCESS");
                            $('#popup').html('<p style="text-align:center;">Your message has been sent.</p>');
                        },
                        error : function(data) {
                            alert("ERROR");
                        }
                });
            }
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
        $('#popupshadow, a.cancel').click(function(event) {
            $('#popup, #popupshadow').animate({opacity:0},500).delay(500).queue(function() { $(this).remove(); });
        });
    });
});
```

The PHP script:

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $subject = 'Contact Form - http://visionprintmedia.com';

    $message = '<style type="text/css">
                    #wrap {
                        width:400px;
                        margin:30px auto;
                        border:1px #000000 solid;
                    }
                    header {
                        width:100%;
                        height:50px;
                        display:block;
                    }
                    header h1 {
                        font-size:18px;
                        margin:0px;
                        padding-left:5px;
                        padding-top:15px;
                    }
                    table {
                        width:100%;
                    }
                    table td {
                        vertical-align:text-top;
                    }
                    table td:first-child {
                        width:75px;
                    }
                    a {
                        color:#333333;
                        text-decoration:none;
                    }
                    a:hover {
                        text-decoration:underline;
                    }
                </style>
                <div id="wrap">
                    <header>
                        <h1>Contact Form - http://visionprintmedia.com</h1>
                    </header>
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>Name:</td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Email:</td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Phone:</td><td>'.$phone.'</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>Message:</td><td>'.$message.'</td></tr>
                    </table>
                    <footer>
                        This message was sent to '.$to.' as part of an automated contact form.  If you do not believe that you should have received this email, please forward this message to design@nickentin.com and we will resolve the issue.
                    </footer>
                </div>';

    $headers = 'From: noreply@visionprintmedia.com' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" .
               'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
               'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    //mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    mail('design@nickentin.com',$subject,$message,$headers); // FOR TESTING ONLY
?>
```

I have a live version at http://nickentin.com/design/projects/visionprintmedia/contact.html.  Just click on one of the email links.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to submit your form as AJAX. Check out my answer on how to handle it as an AJAX input. Need more explanation, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change some stuff here:

```
<form class="contact" action="#" method="none">
```

**Replace** it as:

```
<form class="contact" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
```

This is the **HTML** for the form not to be submitted as a normal form. Next, to make sure the AJAX function is called, you need to add this:

```
<form class="contact" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return postAjax(this);">
```

And the **JavaScript function** `postAjax(form)` should be defined as:

```
function postAjax(form)
{
     var post = form.serialize();
     // Send the `post` to the server using your AJAX function.
}
```

In your **PHP Script**, do this:

```
if(mail(...))
    die("OK");
else
    die("Error! Unable to send mail!");
```

In your JavaScript, for that PHP code, use this inside the AJAX Receive function:

```
if(response == "OK")
    alert("Mail Sent");
else
    alert(response);
```

Hope this helps you! :) All the best! :)

Answer (score 1):

You get all the fields of form in post. but what is the value of "to" which you mentioned it in data. You have used that in php 
script. try to give some value in the form  or remove this "$to = $_POST['to'];"in the php script.

Comment: Just before I close the form, I have this: `<input type="hidden" name="to" value="' + $(this).attr('href').slice(7) + '"/>` The point is that whatever link you clicked on, it takes the address after "mailto:" and sets that as the to field of the email.

Comment: just print the values of post then you will know what the values in the "to". I have the doubt on the "to " value

Comment: Ahh, I see what happened.  I put the field in the form, but never converted it to a variable.  Now it works.  Thank you for your help.